# Cordova Android Pay Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, payment

Can someone tell me if there is a Cordova plugin available that supports Android Pay?  I see plugins that support Google in-app purchases but not Android Pay.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Android pay means payement integration through paypal ?

Comment: No, android pay described here [link](https://developers.google.com/android-pay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, there is no cordova plugin available for android pay. If required, you can write custom plugin for it.